# Writing SQL Queries Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having some trouble with writing this query. This is what I have so far:

**Find the name of the customer that deposited the highest amount with one transaction (include the transaction amount).**

```
select name, amount
from customer, transaction, account
where account.owner_ssn = customer.ssn
and account.type = transaction.type
order by transaction.amount desc 
limit by one;
```

**This is the bank database: **

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    name VARCHAR(20),
    sex CHAR(1),
    ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    phone CHAR(15),
    dob DATE,
    address VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(ssn)

);
    
CREATE TABLE account (
    number CHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    open_date DATE,
    type CHAR(20),
    owner_ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(number)
    );
    
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    id INT(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(9,2),
    tdate DATE,
    type CHAR(10),
    account_num CHAR(16),
    PRIMARY KEY(id) 
);
```

Comment: sorry about that Im new at using StackOverflow. I don't really understand the differences between MySQL and SQL server, apologies. I removed the tag. What do you mean by yelling? Sorry if I conveyed that! I just thought I'd make one single post since its all with writing queries with that one database. As for results Im not sure the questions are pretty clear.

Comment: I see your problems, your porposed solution and some details, but what's your question?

Comment: The fourth one is giving me an error and I'm not sure if the first three are right.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server and two completely different database engines. Yelling is having your title ALL IN CAPITALS. Questions should only ask a single question. To ask a good SQL question it should always have sample data, expected results and your attempt - it might be clear to you, but you're its more work for others to understand. Sample Data + Expected results is a very clear way to demonstrate what you are hoping to achieve. And if you provide sample data as DDL+DML then people can copy and paste out to test.

Comment: "I'm not sure if the first three are right." - exactly why you need sample data and expected results - so you can determine whether its working or not. The first part of writing a query is being clear what it needs to accomplish i.e. how the data should look.

Comment: okay sorry about that I'll delete the question.

Comment: @CompTech You may add sample data as insert statement. What are the values of type in transaction table. Your third query might be wrong. It's not showing balance rather the list of amount for that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will return the customer name with amount who deposited highest amount in a single transaction. If there is more than one customer with same highest amount then the first one to deposited that will be selected.

```
select name, amount
from customer c inner join account a
on c.ssn=a.owner_ssn
inner join transaction t 
on a.type = t.type
order by t.amount desc, t.tdate
limit 1;
```